# Any simple way in ionic2/angular2 to disable button if a text input area is empty?

Tags: ionic2, angular2-forms, disabled-control

I'm trying to use an *ngIf conditional on a button in order to disable it if a text input area is empty, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to access that input value.

```
<ion-item>

<ion-label fixed>Venue</ion-label>

    <ion-input type="text" id="venue" [(ngModel)]="event.venue" class="form-control" maxlength="22" required></ion-input> 

    </ion-item>

<button ion-button block id="addEventButton" *ngIf="//not sure what to do here// " (click)="addEvent();">Add Event</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this will work

```
<button ion-button block id="addEventButton" [disabled]="!event.venue"></button>
```